# C++: read() from pipe - random EINTR and EACCESS errors

Tags: c++, fork, pipe

I am trying to use pipe and fork in C++. I use the functions below to read from and write to the pipe. It nearly always works as expected, except that I sometimes (randomly) get `nbytes = -1`, with errno = 4 (EINTR, system interruption), or `nbytes = 0`, with errno = 13 (EACCESS, access denied).

When I get (nbytes, errno) = (-1, 4), can I just sleep a couple of milliseconds, try to read again and hope to get the message ?

Same question with (nbytes, errno) = (0, 13)? If not, any reason why I randomly get an access denied?

Also, I understand that it is possible to get nbytes > 0 but smaller than the expected nb of chars. Will readbuffer contain the incomplete message in that case? Can I call read() again with the number of missing char to get the remaining ones?

```
int size_digits = 10;
void read_from_pipe (int file, std::istringstream & is)
{
    char readbuffer[size_digits];
    // Receive size of the message first
    int nbytes = read(file, readbuffer, size_digits);
    if(nbytes != size_digits){
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Failed when reading from pipe - nbytes:" << nbytes << ", size_digits:" << size_digits << ", errno: " << errno;
        throw(oss.str());
    }
    int buffer_size = atoi(readbuffer);
    char readbuffer2[buffer_size];
    nbytes = read(file, readbuffer2, buffer_size);
    if(nbytes != buffer_size){
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Failed when reading from pipe - nbytes:" << nbytes << ", buffer_size:" << buffer_size << ", errno: " << errno;
        throw(oss.str());
    }
    is.str(readbuffer2);
    return;
}

void
write_to_pipe (int file, std::ostringstream & os)
{
const char* c_str = os.str().c_str();
char writebuffer[size_digits];
sprintf(writebuffer,"%10d", int(strlen(c_str)));
// Send size of the message first
write(file, writebuffer, size_digits);
// Now send the message
write(file, c_str, strlen(c_str));
return;
}
```

Comment: `sprintf(writebuffer,"%10d", int(strlen(c_str)));` is going to need at least 11 chars in that buffer, not 10. You're invoking undefined behavior. You also need to take `c_str()` *after* you populate the stream; not before. In fact (grey to me right now, as I'm not currently caffeinated) you likely need a local as opposed to the temp that can be gone as soon as the statement is finished.

Comment: is it because of the \0 at the end of the string? And why "at least 11", and not exactly 11? I am trying to get the exact nb of chars to be able to reuse the pipe at will...

Comment: among other things, that'd be one.

Comment: Not that you'll likely exceed it, but `std::size_t` is often a `unsigned long`, the domain of which is not inclusive in `int`. Its implementation-dependent. C++ § 18.2p6 [support.types] "The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object." Were I you I would write the size as a string, followed by a space, then content. the size can then be read as a whitespace-delimited string formatted to `std::size_t`, then the content thereafter. Just me, but it would seem to make your code considerably simpler.

Comment: I tried to replace all `int` by size_t, I still get the same issue with EINTR - although the EACCESS seems to not happen anymore. Also, if I send the length of the string at the beginning of the string itself before a whitespace, do I then need to read characters one by one until the whitespace and then the message?

Comment: EINTR is a non-fatal error -- if you get it, you should just try the call again.   (see http://250bpm.com/blog:12 for the ugly details about why EINTR exists)

Comment: Guys, many thanks for your comments and suggestions; it works well now!